# Does Undertow's Acces Log Time Indicate Request Recieve Time or Request Completion TIme?

Tags: wildfly, undertow

I'm working with Undertow + JBoss, and had a question.  The standard time facility will log date and time as per the javadoc on the [AccessLogHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/accesslog/AccessLogHandler.java).  However, I can't find anything to indicate whether this is the time the request was received, or whether this was the time that the request was completed.

I took a peek at [DateTimeAttribute](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/attribute/DateTimeAttribute.java), and it appears that it would be a dynamically generated statistic when readAttribute() is called.  That method is called a couple dozen times in the undertow core code, but I want to believe this method is the main use in a request/response flow (found in AccessLogHandler):

```
    private class AccessLogCompletionListener implements ExchangeCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void exchangeEvent(final HttpServerExchange exchange, final NextListener nextListener) {
        try {
            if(predicate == null || predicate.resolve(exchange)) {
                accessLogReceiver.logMessage(tokens.readAttribute(exchange));
            }
        } finally {
            nextListener.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

So if I'm understanding this code correctly, it would appear that this timestamp is generated *after* the request has been completed.  Can anyone confirm that this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a completion time. You can test this by noting your PC clock, doing a long request, e.g. by setting a breakpoint in your servlet or other UI code, doing a `Thread.sleep(30000)`, and then seeing the timestamp in the access log.